# pygame, how to show character on screen for 3 seconds then go away

Tags: surface

I am using Pygame and I want a player to show up for 3 seconds and if they are shot then they go away but if they stay for more than three seconds the health bar decreases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `pygame`, you could approach this in the following way:

```
import pygame

class Player
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.creation_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        ...
```

& then you can simply check if a certain amount of time has passed

```
player = Player()

while True:
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= player.creation_time + 3000:
        if not player.hit: 
            player.health = max(player.health-1, 0) # decrease health until 0
        if player.hit or player.health is 0:
            player.die()
    ...
```

`pygame.time.get_ticks()` returns the milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called, and so this must be converted to seconds when being used, and `pygame.init()` must have been called.

Comment: Note that this will decrease player health by 1 every frame, so unless your player has unreasonably large health, you may want to change the decrease a bit.

Comment: I imported time but time.time() does not work, I have also tried to use pygame.tick.clock which does not work either. Do I need to import something else?

Comment: `pygame.time.Clock` is a class and so calling it will only return an object. You can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` however! I have updated my answer for this.

Comment: If this does not work, please share the code in your question and I will take a look at it.